# blender layout modes vs workspace

Tags: interface, workflow

I want to know something. Under *Layout Workspace* I can see many modes(object, edit, sculpt etc). Again there are separate workspace like  Modeling, sculpting!

what Object mode under layout workspace exactly is?

what is the difference in staying object mode (Layout)press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and go to *edit mode*.

vs

going to *modeling* workspace from layout workspace's object mode?

Is edit mode in layout same as Modeling workspace?

[image]

Comment: Please use proper tags for your questions. The [tag:blender-internal-render-engine] is for questions about the legacy render engine *Blender Internal* that was shipped with Blender 2.79 and earlier versions.If you have questions about the user interface please use the corresponding tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit* mode, whether you are in the *Layout* workspace or in the *Modeling* workspace, is exactly the same.

*Edit* mode, *Object* mode, *Sculpt* mode, etc, determine how you will interact with the object, while workspaces like *Layout, Modeling, Sculpting*, etc, are just different organizations of the interface windows, they are supposed to be better adapted to your needs when you want to model, sculpt, etc.

Of course depending on the workspace you choose your object may automatically switch to *Edit* interaction mode or *Sculpt* mode, etc, but it will be the exact same mode as if you'd stayed in any workspace and switched the interaction mode to *Edit* or *Sculpt*.

Actually you can ignore the different workspaces, stay into the *Layout* workspace and reorganize the windows as you want.

Comment: HI, Is that Durate Ramos guy a bot/ he kept pasting that below my question! :@ Each time I picked that tag! what's wrong with him?

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: Isn't my question about UI? I USED PROPRER TAG!  :@

Comment: Hi @RussianBlue !  Duarte is one of the mods (so am I). He simply pointed out the standard usage of the tag in this site. Please don't take this personally, rather have a look at the [tag wiki](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/blender-internal-render-engine/info) which gives some guidance as to the intended usage of a tag for this site. I have edited your question to include `interface` and `workflow` tags to help with organization.

Comment: Hi, I attached a picture, Kindly check! Those are the tags am getting! So without blender-internal-render-engine which one is more appropriate you think for my question?

Comment: NO 'Blender Internal' I SEE!

Comment: @RussianBlue 1: He is no bot. 2: He keeps pointing that out because you use it although you're questions are not about rendering (especially not with the legacy render engine). 3: Yes, your question is about the user interface, but that was nowhere in your tags. 4: Stop entering "blend" in the tag search field, since this site is about Blender all tags are Blender related - use something like "interface" if it's about the interface.

Comment: :'( :'( :'( No I didn't take personally. I felt upset. He kept writing that from day 1. Am new here.I need time to get used to it. :'(

Comment: @RussianBlue Yes, you have to get used to it, that's okay. But how should you get used to it if nobody points that out? And if you repeat the error he needs to repeat pointing it out...?

Comment: He could tell me elaborately :'( .

Comment: It's okay I will pick 'Blender Internal' next time.  :(

Comment: I only get those tags. rest don't go with Blender UI. so I kept using that, :( . Peace

Comment: @RussianBlue No, don't pick "Blender Internal"... this is what you've been told now several times not to do. Blender Internal Render Engine is an old render engine which isn't used anymore so you're question is not about it unless you are working with a very old version of Blender. I gave you an example: if you're asking about the interface, search for "interface", not "blender". Or "ui" or "user", in each case the search suggests _interface_ with the description: _Questions pertaining to Blender's user interface, such as theming, scripting and operating the interface._

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. I will follow.

Comment: @ Duarte Farrajota Ramos  Sorry for all those wrong tags. I didn't understand. Today it's clear.

Comment: @moonboots In order to better avoid confusion, I would more clearly separate `workspaces` and `interaction modes` in such answer; and explain what they are more exactly.

Comment: @L0Lock Ok I'm going to reformulate